# Nested Squares using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Just using HTML and CSS, is there a way to create nested squares.
in another words, one big square A, and another square inside A(let's call this B), and another square inside B, etc etc continue like that about 10 times. The Squares need to be centered within each squares. also the each squares need to be different colors.
thank you!

Comment: Just nest 10 divs and set their size to be square

Comment: yes, it is possible. please describe a more specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to be more specific, but here is a simple example of how.

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div>
    </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}

div {
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**Edit based on your new info**

Vertical aligning elements to the middle seems to require setting the wrapper to display:table; and setting the inner divs to display:table-cell; and vertical-align:middle. However, this causes the backround colors to all take the bottom most cell's color when nested... so I just just absolute positioning instead to vertical align:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap"> 
    <div id="a" class="z"><div id="b" class="z"><div id="c" class="z"><div id="d" class="z"><div id="e" class="z"><div id="f" class="z"><div id="g" class="z"><div id="h" class="z"><div id="i" class="z"><div id="j" class="z">
        </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#wrap{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
}

.z {
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:5%;
}

#a{background-color:#aaa}
#b{background-color:#999}
#c{background-color:#888}
#d{background-color:#777}
#e{background-color:#666}
#f{background-color:#555}
#g{background-color:#444}
#h{background-color:#333}
#i{background-color:#222}
#j{background-color:#111}
```

Comment: thank you for the tip. The Squares need to be centered within each squares. also the each squares need to be different colors. I'm trying with what you said but could you please help me little more? like how do you center them? text-align:center wouldn't work.

Comment: thank you so much. It's amazing that you understood exactly what I meant. It was so hard to explain without a picture. I can work on this from here. but just one more thing please? how do I control the distance between each box? can they be consistent in thickness? instead of having the size relative to the outer box.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on the basics of how the "box model" works. Check out this site, explains everything clearly on how to set margins, padding, etc: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp